# Where can I find exact dimensions of a base of Eiffel Tower?

Tags: tolerance

I am looking and looking and I can't find it: what are exact measurements of a base of Eiffel Tower in centimeters (or precision equivalent in imperial, not picky, can convert). All I can find everywhere is 125 meters on the side, which is impossible. Height is not a problem, it's all over, but base is apparently not important... Did no one measured it after it was built? Or something?

Anybody can share a source for those, please?

Comment: Why is 125 meters on the side impossible?

Comment: @Chris_abc - because this would be the first ever construction where builders did everything exactly according to the design... No building designed with 125m on the side has exactly 125m. Each side will have different length, within several centimetres. This phenomenon in construction is covered by something called "Dimension tolerance". And I need to know how close to the design the actual thing is.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search of "design drawings of Eiffel tower", I found a thesis which models the Eiffel Tower in CAD software, according to the original drawings:

Narayana, S. (2020). 3D Modelling of Eiffel Tower using the Original Drawings

You should be able to find it on Google Scholar easily.

On a drawing called "elevation drawing", the base dimensions are shown. I'm not 100% sure if those are the drawings that were truly used for building the Eiffel Tower, or just preliminary design drawings.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. My bad and I just edited the question. I need measurements, not design dimensions. Those two are never the same. Thank you, though, it is a nice find.

Comment: I honestly doubt you're going to find that anywhere to a precision of centimeters. I don't see why anyone would have made the effort to measure it, and those measurements may change over time due to temperature differences anyway.
Out of curiosity: Can I ask why you need those exact measurements?

Comment: Oh, someone most certainly did measure it, and did it with high precision and accuracy (probably won't be far off if I'd say they did it with sub-1cm accuracy)... Those people are called surveyors. And as for why - I want to know the actual dimension tolerance to compare with other buildings, for a project of mine.

Comment: @AcePL Fair point. It may be possible to figure out who is the periodic surveyor and ask them directly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find this is by using a vector cadastral plan.
City of Paris has one available.
https://capgeo.sig.paris.fr/Apps/ParisPLU/

It tells measurements of what's been built and not what's been planned.

You can measure the base online or download pdf or svg file
of the area and check dimensions using another software.

[image]
([source](https://capgeo.sig.paris.fr/Apps/ParisPLU/))

higher accuracy would require to take into account when these distances are measured, depending on temperature and to date painting job.
(There can be up to 20 layers of paint that may have been removed in 2021(?), this might change the length of the base by 6mm)

Comment: That is an amazing find, thank you. I'll try it later in the office, where I can use 4k and try to measure it, because now, on my laptop, all I get is 123,5m on a side. And steel's temperature expansion is not an issue for me, this would be precise enough. Honestly, down to 5 cm precision is sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0):

They have their own site: https://www.toureiffel.paris/en/the-monument/key-figures.

The width of the base is 410 feet according to their [data](https://www.toureiffel.paris/en/the-monument/key-figures).

Comment: that's very close to the 125 m in OP's post